# CNN Training Runs without error, but it does not display the results

Tags: conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am new to pytorch, and I am trying to train my model (CNN), using the following code:

The program runs fine, but it does not display this Epoch/Step/Loss/Accuracy part:

```
print(‘Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.2f}%’
```

as `if (i+1) % 100 == 0:` never turns to 0

Training part:

```
iter = 0

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(dataloaders['train']):
        images = Variable(images)
        labels = Variable(labels)

        # Clear the gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward propagation
        outputs = model(images)

        # Calculating loss with softmax to obtain cross entropy loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        # Backward prop
        loss.backward()

        # Updating gradients
        optimizer.step()

        iter += 1

        # Total number of labels
        total = labels.size(0)


        # Obtaining predictions from max value
        _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)



        # Calculate the number of correct answers
        correct = (predicted == labels).sum().item()

        # Print loss and accuracy

        if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
            print('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.2f}%'
                  .format(epoch + 1, num_epochs, i + 1, len(dataloaders['train']), loss.item(),
                          (correct / total) * 100))
```

Full Code:

https://pastebin.com/dshNmhRL

Comment: How long did you wait? Maybe it just takes longer than you expect?
Try changing `if (i+1) % 100 == 0` to `if (i+1) % 1 == 0` to get output after every iteration. Or if `i` ***really*** never reaches 100 than your dataset might be just too small :)

Comment: @blue-phoenox thankyou so much!  it works fine now :)